# Finding the orthogonal complement of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, orthogonality

Let $V$ be the vector space $\{(x,y,z,w)\in\mathbb{R}^4:x+y-z=0\ \text{and}\ x+y+w=0\}$. Then, what would be a basis for the orthogonal complement of $V$.

I think we have to find the null space of the column space spanned by the above two vectors, i.e, the null space of
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\1&1&0&0\\2&0&0&0\\0&-2&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
Am I right? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: What is $t$ in the definition of $V$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks again! edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $V$ is the space of those vectors $v\in\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\bigl\langle v,(1,1,-1,0)\bigr\rangle=\bigl\langle v,(1,1,0,1)\bigr\rangle=0$. Since $(1,1,-1,0)$ and $(1,1,0,1)$ are linearly independent, they form the basis that you aer after.

Comment: how did you arrive at that?

Comment: At what? Are you talking about my first sentence or the second one?

Comment: I meant, what is $v$ in this case?

Comment: The vector $v$ is a vector of the form $(x,y,z,w)$, with $x,y,z,w\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: thanks! so just remove the variables out and form the dot product, right? Quite easy!

Comment: Yes, it's just that.